# Mesh unwraps in undesired way (seams are not obeyed)

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have bird model with symmetric wings on its left and right side. Wings are cutted by the seams from the rest of the body. One wing unwraps correctly, following the seam but second doens't. No matter if there is a seam or not the wing always unwraps as if there was some seam. Even with my symmetric seam it unwraps like there was some extra seam near to my.

I attached the screenshot of unwraped model with selected undesired edge cut.

Here is link to blend file:
https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/db48ae49a47dd31103bb5bdd1c233aaa20160405141634/d98e72b1b5847bc4dde682751860aaba20160405141634/a98a07

[image: Mesh unwraps in undesired way. Seams are not obeyed.]

Comment: Could be that some geometry is disconnected. See if selecting all and doing a Remove Doubles operation helps. It would help if you could [post the blend.](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: I removed doubles but it didn't help. Link to blend file above the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mesh has some problems.  You have not joined the wing to the body correctly which has left unconnected edges and interior faces. This is the cause of the extra UV islands.

You can see the problem area by clicking Select -> Select All By Trait -> Non-manifold.  You should remove the interior faces and connect the wing to body for the mesh to unwrap properly.

You also have several nasty poles that may affect the way the mesh deforms once rigged.  If you are intending to fix these, it might be worth altering the topology before you UV the mesh.

[image]

Comment: Indeed there were interior faces. I didn't notice them. Thank You!

Comment: What you mean by "You also have several nasty poles that may affect the way the mesh deforms once rigged." Can you explain to me of what poles are you thinking and how can they affect the mesh?

Comment: You may want to look at the neck and tail area where you have poles on curved surfaces. They may affect the deformation of these areas by introducing pinching and uneven subdivision.

Comment: I'm beginner. I'm doing my best regarding to topology. I think I don't understand you enough to fix it. I can't see the problem.